# Displaying a message to the user if they have already booked the same hotel

Tags: php, mysql

I have a hotel booking reservation system that allows the users to book a hotel of their selection. However, I want to display a message for the user if they have already booked the same hotel.

Here is the code that I tried to use but didn't work. Every time I run the code, it always seems to display the code without placing the button (even though if the user hasn't booked a hotel).

```
$hotel_id = $id;

//check if username exists
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM book WHERE hotel_id = 
    '".$hotel_id."' AND username = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."' ";

$thisresult = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($thisresult)>=1){
        echo "You have already booked this hotel";
} else {
    echo "<button style='margin-left: -420px; margin-top: 220px;' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>"; 
}
```

The table that i am using in mysql;

```
Table name: Book
id(int 11),
username(varchar 30), 
hotel_id(int 11),
phone(varchar 50),
date(),
num_nights(int 60)
num_rooms(int 4)
```

Comment: you realize that you're open to an sql injection that could bring down your database, and without notice I might add.

Comment: Have you learned nothing about security from our previous conversations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your count query returns one row in all times.

Try to use this query for your code

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM book WHERE hotel_id = '".$hotel_id."' AND username = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";
```

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard author don't ask about SQL injection protection. I think you notice is wrong in that case

Comment: @JayBlanchard I said it before that i don't need to include security features in my website. And please don't stop others from providing me with answers from my questions. If you really want me to post things about security things then i won't because i said why 5 times before. If you don't like it, then please don't waste your time posting here. thanks!

Comment: It's not that I don't like it @AmirHD, it's that teaching bad habits is just plain wrong. It is my prerogative to continue to warn you and others about these dangers and I have provided support for why I do. I do not consider it a waste of time and I am not trying to prevent others from answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First, store `$_SESSION['user_name']` in a variable:

```
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']
```

Prepare and bind your select statement:

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM book WHERE hotel_id = ? AND username = ?");

$sql->bind_param("is", $hotel_id, $user_name); // Pass your variables as parameters, the "is" denotes that your parameters are of type integer and string

$thisresult = $sql->execute(); // Execute your prepared statement
```

Get the `COUNT` of the `id` column and check to see if it is greater than 1:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($thisresult)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
}
if ($id >= 1) {
    echo "You have already booked this hotel";
} else {
    echo "<button style='margin-left: -420px; margin-top: 220px;' type='submit'> <a href='booknow.php?id=".$id."'> Book now!</a></button>";
}
```

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show that I tested this code on my own machine and it worked for me. Also, the OP was not asking for how to prevent SQL injection; they simply needed to know if 1 or more rows already existed in their table. I was trying to answer directly rather than rewriting all of their code.

Comment: You have updated your answer but still did not provide an explanation of what you did. As for the SQL injection problem I have provided supporting links showing why teaching the right way to do things is far better than continuing to support dangerous coding methods.

Comment: My answer now includes a step-by-step explanation of what the code is doing and how to solve the problem. I have also included the mysqli prepare, bind, and execute statements so that other people who look at this question will see how to avoid potential security threats - even though the OP did not need them himself in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your tips!